# How does PHP password_hash protect the password? Not asking about hashing but rather the overall flow

Tags: php, web-services, hash, passwords

In many basic PHP user logins, a password_hash is used to hash the password for database storage. I get the process of hashing, how to use password_hash, and why this is being done but what I don't understand is how this actually protects the password? I feel as if I might be missing something.

Correct me if I'm wrong but PHP is almost exclusively ran on the server side. Doesn't this mean that the plain password is being sent and then hashed when it reaches the server? Wouldn't this allow for others to pick out the password in transport?

My apologies if this has been asked before. I've tried to do a search prior to asking this but all hits came up as the actual mechanics of password_hash.

Comment: That is you need to use https

Comment: @John This seems to defeat the idea of hashing the password doesn't it? My understanding is that you're saying that password safety is reliant on https vs http rather password_hashing.

Comment: @annihil8ted Not at all. Password hashing protects the password once it's in the database. HTTPS protects it during transit. Two different security measures against two different attack vectors.

Comment: Gotcha! Okay that makes total sense when you break it down that way. I had lumped the two together.

To check my understanding, https is to protect against picking out the password during transit whereas hashing will help protect your database against those who have access and a list of plain passwords?

Comment: Essentially. See my answer for more details, but yes. HTTPS protects the contents of a message in transit, and password hashing ensures any database dumps don't immediately give away every user's password, which is a bad thing because [password reuse is so common](https://xkcd.com/792/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `password_hash` does hashing serverside. Network sniffing would allow the password to be recovered—but you could get into an account by sniffing unencrypted traffic easily anyway.

What password hashing intends to do is protect a user's password in the event of a database breach/dump, preventing users' passwords from being harvested (easily—they can still be brute-forced with a lot of time and effort). It *doesn't* protect the password in-transit, that's what HTTPS is for. Whereas hashing protects once the password makes it to the server, HTTPS ensures that only the intended recipient of the message (in this case, the server) can read the contents and ensure it hasn't been tampered with.

Password hashing is there to protect users from themselves. A lot of users use common passwords or [continually reuse the same password for many sites](https://xkcd.com/792/). Password hashing is there, again, to protect users' passwords behind a one-way mathematical function which should at the very least slow down any potential attackers by making the plain text password unavailable.

Comment: Fantastic explanation, thanks! I see that my understanding above in the comments was correct.

Answer (score 0):

You never send a password over the internet that isn't protected by an SSL cert. That way, the password is protected in transit until it gets to the endpoint and decrypted on the server.

This process is invisible to developers as long as the security certificate is in place and functioning correctly. That's not to say there are not other risks but that mitigates most of it.